# PHP - Java read int8 from String

Tags: java, php, string, numbers, int

How could i translate this PHP-Code to Java Code?

```
protected function readInt24()
{
    $ret = 0;
    if (strlen($this->_input) >= 3)
    {
        $ret  = ord(substr($this->_input, 0, 1)) << 16;
        $ret |= ord(substr($this->_input, 1, 1)) << 8;
        $ret |= ord(substr($this->_input, 2, 1)) << 0;
        $this->_input = substr($this->_input, 3);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

$input is a quite crazy String which contains utf characters (afaik): �8� or so

Comment: The result should be an integer.

Comment: what part do you have problem with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 `ord(substr($this->_input, ..., ...))` retrieves the ASCII values of the three first characters of the string.  For each there is then a left shift which is then or'ed with return.

This would translate in Java as something like:

```
public static int readInt24(String input) {
int ret = 0;
if (input.length() >= 3) {
    ret = input.charAt(0) << 16;
    ret |= input.charAt(1) << 8;
    ret |= input.charAt(2) << 0;
}
return ret;
}
```

Note that the PHP code then truncates the instance variable `_input` to be just 3 char long.